# Scanner input/output formatting wrong

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner

This code is returning the right end result, but the formatting of the inputs and outputs in the console is not correct.

Here's the desired outcome:

```
Type your age: hello
Type your age: ?
Type your age: 3.14
Type your age: 25
Type your GPA: a
Type your GPA: bcd
Type your GPA: 2.5
age = 25, GPA = 2.5
```

The program keeps asking for age and GPA respectively until it gets the correct inputs, and then prints them.

Here's What I'm getting:

```
Type your age: hello
Type your age: ?
Type your age: 3.14
25
Type your GPA: a
Type your GPA: bcd
2.5
age = 25, GPA = 2.5
```

As you can see, same result, but the formatting is incorrect. I'm certain it has to do with the way I'm using the scanner object, but my understanding of Scanner is currently limited.

Here's the bare code:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Type your age: ");
console.next();
while (!console.hasNextInt()) {
  System.out.print("Type your age: ");
  console.next();
}
int age = console.nextInt();

System.out.print("Type your GPA: ");
console.next();
while (!console.hasNextDouble()) {
  System.out.print("Type your GPA: ");
  console.next();
}
double gpa = console.nextDouble();
System.out.println("age = " + age + ", GPA = " + gpa);
```

Comment: What's the point of having these two `console.next();` before the `while` loops?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `console.next()` before the while loop altogether, you dont need it. You will then have the required output. When you have the `console.next()`, you are looking for and returning another complete token, which you simply don't need in your case.

```
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type your age: ");
        while (!console.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Type your age: ");
            console.next();
        }

        int age = console.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Type your GPA: ");

        while (!console.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.print("Type your GPA: ");
            console.next();
        }

        double gpa = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("age = " + age + ", GPA = " + gpa);
```